# PostgreSQL - subtract 'days' from a returned 'date' value without also returning timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm querying a table to get some date, like so:

```
SELECT date - INTERVAL '10 day' AS date
FROM example_table
WHERE username = 'Bob'
LIMIT 1;
```

The `date` column in the `example_table` does *not* have a timestamp. All dates in the column are stored in the following manner:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

The query above will return a result like so:

```
2016-11-20 00:00:00.000000
```

It takes the date found, goes back 10 days, and returns that date. But I want it to return the date without adding the timestamp, like so:

```
2016-11-20
```

If I use `INTERVAL` it always seems to add a timestamp. Is there a way to *only* get the date?

Comment: `date` is a really bad choice for a column name because it's also a keyword. Plus it doesn't document what kind of "date" that is. The "due date"? The "birth date"? The "registration date"? The "expiration date"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine (but can be simplified, as demonstrated by a_horse_with_no_name). What you are seeing is a display issue. You can format your date to a string in the relevant format using `to_char()`:

```
SELECT to_char("date" - INTERVAL '10 day', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS "date"
FROM example_table
WHERE username = 'Bob'
LIMIT 1;
```

Note: `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` does not make sense: if there is more than one record in the resultset, you actually get a random record out of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `interval` notation and convert back to a date:

```
SELECT (date - INTERVAL '10 day')::date AS date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract (or add) an integer from a `date`. That integer represents the number of days:

```
SELECT "date" - 10 AS "date"
FROM example_table
WHERE username = 'Bob'
LIMIT 1;
```